# Change height of view programmatically in uistackview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistackview

I need to change the view height in the stack view when I press the test button, but it is not working properly.

When I press the test button, I want to set the height of view 3 to 50 and the height of view5 to fill the remaining area. When I press the test button again, i want to reverse to process. How can I do that?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You really should be using autolayout instead of frames, then you would just change the size of the constraint and place view.layoutIfNeeded() in an animation block.

Comment: Also please don't post image of code. Copy paste the code to the question. So that people trying to help can answer without having to type the whole thing again. Storyboard images are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SeanLintern88 mentioned, the way you really should be doing this is with auto layout constraints -- you don't want to be mixing setFrame with autolayout.

IBOutlet the height constraints for View 3 and View 5.  Set the View 3 height constraint as inactive to start (if you want it to look like your storyboard does currently to start), then whenever the button is pressed, check which constraint is active and flip-flop them.

[image: StackView_View_Resize]

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nullable) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view3HeightConstraint;
@property (strong, nullable) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view5HeightConstraint;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // start us out as inactive
    self.view3HeightConstraint.active = NO;
}

- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.view5HeightConstraint.active) {
        // view 5 height constraint is active
        // you can set the height constants directly in storyboard as well
        self.view3HeightConstraint.constant = 50.0f;
        self.view3HeightConstraint.active = YES;
        self.view5HeightConstraint.active = NO;
    } else {
        // view 3 is height constraint is active
        // you can set the height constants directly in storyboard as well
        self.view5HeightConstraint.constant = 50.0f;
        self.view5HeightConstraint.active = YES;
        self.view3HeightConstraint.active = NO;
    }
    // animate the layoutIfNeeded so we can get a smooth animation transition
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}


@end
```